# Vimtex compiling different file in folder opens new zathura window

Tags: vim-latex

I am using vimtex to write a latex document, and my main tex file refers to many different tex files in the folder. If I am editing a specific tex file and save I automatically see changes in zathura where pdf is open. But if I switch to a different file and make edits and save, the changes are not reflected. After compiling \ll zathura opens a new window where the changes are visible. I was wondering if there was a way of avoiding having to open a new window every time I make edit on a different file from where the continuous compilation was started?

Comment: I also use vimtex with many input files and noticed issues unless I follow the following incantation:
1. Open vim on the "main file" (whether or not you want to edit this file)

2. Hit `\ll` to start autocompilation (still in main file)

3. Start editing/saving the actual fie you want to edit. 

The udates should work now

Comment: Thanks!! this worked.

Comment: Great, I'll make it an answer so others can find it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using vimtex autocompletion in projects that include other compilable files, you need to start autocompilation in the main file.

1. Open the main file that includes your other files
2. Start autocompilation from the main file (normal shortcut is `\ll`)
3. Start editing the actual files you want to edit

Autocompilation should work as expected now.

---

*Note from OP (see comment):* Keep the main file open for autocompletion to continue working.

Comment: small comment, you should leave the main.tex file where you started autocompilation open in a different window.(If you close it compilation stops)

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to my answer, I admit that I leave it open in a tab by habit and didn't know it was needed for it to work.